# Docker Container Running Previous Version of Code

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm still learning how to use Docker. I was trying to add Docker to my Spring Boot app, but it's not going as smoothly as I expected.

In the beginning, I had an endpoint that returned 'Hello, World.' I ran the app with Docker, and it worked. Then, I removed this endpoint and added another one. After that, I added a PostgreSQL database to the app and ran it with Docker again. However, it still only returned the result of the first endpoint that I removed. The second endpoint didn't exist. I don't know where I went wrong.

this is my dockerfile

```
    FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
    ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
    COPY ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: pfa
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not say how you're starting the container(s). I guess you're just using `docker compose up`. Then you need to update the image: either remove the "old" image or rebuild by

```
docker compose build
```

before `docker compose up` or simply

```
docker compose up --build
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a docker cache issue, in your docker file:

```
COPY ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
```

Since this line has not changed its name docker is assuming there aren't changes in your docker image, so the docker build step is not being considered.

To avoid this issue you must run containers with the following switch:

```
docker-compose up –no-cache
```